# Inline-Block not moving images to horizontal row

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get these images to be in a row side by side. I am following a tutorial for a class assignment and as far as I know the code is perfectly fine. The images are the child of Choices, within the Choice class but for some reason I cannot get the images side by side instead of vertical.

```css
.choices {
  margin-top: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.choice {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.choice:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #24273E;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">
  <div class="choice" id="r">
    <img src="imgs/rock.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="choices">
    <div class="choice" id="p">
      <img src="imgs/paper.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="choices">
      <div class="choice" id="s">
        <img src="imgs/scissors.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Screenshot of what is being currently displayed]

I have tried other people's suggestions online but none of them seem to fix the issue.

Comment: You didnt include enough code for us to determine exactly what your structure looks like. But assuming there is 3 `choice` `divs` inside the `choices` `div` you should put your styles on the `choices` as it is the piece that contains the individual items you are hoping to have displayed inline. you could also use `display: flex` on the `choices` `div`

Comment: I went ahead and added more of the HTML for better context, hopefully, that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to add a class of `display: flex` to the class `choices`

```css
.choices {
  margin: 50px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.choice {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  
  
  background-color: red;
}
.choice:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #24273E;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">

  <div class="choice" id="r">
    <img src="imgs/rock.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="choice" id="p">
    <img src="imgs/paper.png" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="choice" id="s">
    <img src="imgs/scissors.png" alt="">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: So I changed to using this code but now the images are not centered on the page like they were before.

Comment: @ChrisBarnard the updated code that you provided is incorrect. Each section has 2 opening `divs` one for `choices` and one for `choice` but only one closing `div` for the 2.

Comment: I added that second div, however, the images are still not centered on the page.

Comment: @ChrisBarnard I have updated my code, unless you have a specific reason for using the `choices` `div` wrapping around each choice, I would update your code to match mine and use the `choices` `div` as a container to hold all the individual `choice` `div`s inside. Using `justify-content: space-around` works with the flex container to position the elements in the center of the flex box and I changed `margin-top: 50px 0` (which is formatted incorrectly) to `margin: 50px 20px;` where 50px is the top/bottom margin and 20px is left/right margin to center the container more.

Comment: Also if you copy the code I have written you will need to remove the `background-color: red;` from the `choice` class, I have it in my code to show the position of the individual `choice` `div`s

Answer (score 0):

place the inline block on .choices and make each .choices wrap each .choice

```css
.choices {
  display: inline-block;
  
  
  
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  width:30vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="choices">
  <div class="choice" id="r">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25" alt="">
</div>
</div>

<div class="choices">
  <div class="choice" id="p">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25" alt="">
</div>
</div>


<div class="choices">
  <div class="choice" id="s">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/25" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your version. For reference, I am using an external style sheet so I have been implementing all of these ideas within the external sheet. I don't know if these ideas are exclusive to internal sheets. When I tried your version, but with my margins added under choices at least, and with the div under every choice as you posted. That caused everything to go back to being vertically aligned.